# Use FCM without launcher or MainActivity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use FCM to send myself some monitoring data. I already implemented a working solution based on the quick starts but because I just want to provide a way to receive notifications, my app is completely useless. I know I can just remove

```
<activity android:name=".Notifications" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

From the manifest to get an app without Launcher, like a background service. Doing so seems to desactivate FCM.

The real question is :

**Can I use FCM without activity, by just implementing services ?**

Comment: How do you plan on registering for FCM? Nothing in your app will run until the user runs your launcher activity or something else uses an explicit `Intent` to invoke a component in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your app at least one time in order to start a `Service` or register a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can find more about this here:

[Android application as a service without activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307412/android-application-as-a-service-without-activity)

Note that after starting, you can just create a `BroadcastReceiver` which detects a device startup, then starts a `Service` and then use `FCM`.

Comment: Isn't starting a service power consumming ? let's say that I manage to start the service only once (for exemple when installing the App using something like adb) does FCM will still work after a phone restart ? If I must start a service at each phone reboot can I launch a one shot service (initialize FCM, register to topics and exit) ? Will do some experiments on my own anyway :) thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes that is possible. It depends if you make the `Service` `STICKY` or not.