# How to create Android application that contains service, without any activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 different apps, its required to create one more app which provides some services to these apps. Since it acts as service provider, UI is not required. How to achieve this? and service should be running in background always

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android application as a service without activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307412/android-application-as-a-service-without-activity)

Comment: somebody has to start that service before it is able to run in background. Who will it be?

Comment: I used to have a Service only Android Wear app back when Wear apps were automatically installed on a user's watch. But I would not really consider a solution like this for the phone. It will only confuse users because they will have nothing to interact with after they manually download your service app from the play store. It sounds like what you really need is a service module and a remote server. Perhaps a ContentProvider. But without any details, it is difficult to comment.

Comment: Start the service from one of those 2 activities you have already started.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko,--- I want to start the service on BOOT_COMPLETE using broadcast receiver